# Why am I getting a nil object instead of a shortlink from bitly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bit.ly, httparty

I'm using a simple enough bitly implementation based on this example: http://www.appelsiini.net/2010/using-bitly-with-httparty

I put this file in the lib folder (bitly.rb)

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'
class Bitly
  include HTTParty
  base_uri "api.bit.ly"

  @@login   = "goldhat"
  @@api_key = "R_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

  def self.shorten(url)
    response = get("/v3/shorten?login=#{@@login}&apiKey=#{@@api_key}&longUrl=#{url}")
    response["data"]["url"]
  end
end
```

For some reason I'm getting a nil object. As though bitly doesn't even respond with any data. I tested it out in my console and my app and get the same error:

```
NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
        from c:/goldhat_production/lib/bitly.rb:9:in `shorten'
        from (irb):1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code works as expected for me.  It seems your error is due to some other issue in your code (given that you're getting an AR::Base error).  Can you paste some more code?

Comment: Hmm, it didn't work in the console though when I type Bitly.shorten("http://stackoverflow.com"), only referring to the code that I pasted above.

Comment: try Bitly.shorten("http://stackoverflow.com")

Comment: That didn't work as expected -- make sure you have the full http :// stackoverflow.com

Comment: oops, meant to say that I typed Bitly.shorten("http : // stackoverflow.com")

Comment: That works fine for me -- double-check your credentials?

Comment: Yeah. Even tried a different bit.ly account just in case.

Comment: Oh wait a sec -- you said you put this in the lib/ folder.  Is this Rails 3?

Comment: The problem is definitely a loading problem, not a problem with the Bitly code.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll try a few different implementations of the same code and see if any work.

Comment: Crap. Sorry about the runaround, but I finally figured out the problem. I thought I was loading the code above when I was loading code that didn't work. Guess I need to get more sleep.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to the DIY - you can find a well-tested Ruby gem for bit.ly [here](https://github.com/philnash/bitly).

Comment: Yeah, this gem worked for me, but requires a version of rubygems currently not supported on my shared server

Comment: Got it -- looking at your code now since it's definitely a simpler approach.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the Bitly code, it's that you're putting it in the lib/ directory in a Rails 3 application.  To get lib/ loaded, you need the following in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```